# multipleSelect() not working properly on dynamically added <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [jQuery Multiple Select](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/) library by wenzhixin.

If I try applying `multipleSelect()` to an element immediately after appending that element to the DOM, the multiple select appears blank (without any options):

[image]

```
var template  = "<select multiple id='multiple-select'>";
    template +=     "<option value='1'>Apples</option>";
    template +=     "<option value='2'>Oranges</option>";
    template += "</select>";

$("#wrapper").html(template)

$("#multiple-select").multipleSelect();
```

However, if I delay the `multipleSelect()` call using `setTimeout()`, it works:

[image]

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#multiple-select").multipleSelect();
}, 5000);
```

Any idea what's going on here? How can I get the library to immediately read the element? Our form is generated dynamically using Javascript.

I've also [filed an issue](https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/issues/183) on the library's GitHub page.

**UPDATE!** I'm making the `multipleSelect()` call on a `<select>` element in a non-active Bootstrap tab. That seems to be related to the issue, and I'm able to recreate it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zbkcgcam/1/. As you can see, the `multipleSelect()` call is being made on the `<select>` element in the 'Search' tab, and when you open the search tab you can see the glitch.

**SOLVED!** You are required to define a width for the `<select>` element, for some reason, if the `<select>` is nested inside a block-level element with `display: none`. See my answer below for more details. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It works without ay issue on [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zbkcgcam/) . Make sure that everything is loaded before you call `.multipleSelect()`

Comment: @phillip100 Thank you for your reply! I'm going to continue exploring this to see if I can narrow the issue down some more and then I will follow up.

Comment: @phillip100 It seems to be related to Bootstrap's tabbing functionality... I'm actually loading the search in the background of a non-visible tab. I am able to replicate the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/zbkcgcam/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Defining a width on the `<select>` element seems to fix the issue. It's strange that the bug only occurs when you call `multipleSelect()` on a `<select>` element that is wrapped in a block-level element with `display: none` set...

My problem was directly related to another issue posted on the library's GitHub page (https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/issues/24) and the solution was found inside.

Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic content you'll either have to set an observer to notice when the content is added, or call your function AFTER the content has been added.

jQuery works asynchronously, so when you're using .html() and using your selector right afterwards, chances are (as in - almost guaranteed) that the html-code has not arrived in the DOM yet. You can use [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) to make sure that your .html() function has finished before using your selector.

Comment: Hi, Kevin. If you notice in the example, I actually am calling `multipleSelect()` after the content has been appended to the DOM. I was able to find a similar issue on the GitHub page that provided a solution (seems to be a weird quirk of the library). Thanks for your input though!

Comment: Hi Andrew, jquery works asynchronously, so wen you're using .html() and using your selector right afterwards, chances are (as in - almost guaranteed) that the html-code has not arrived in the DOM yet. You could use .promise(), I'll update my answer.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for clarifying. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a specific class to the select on its "creation" time
Also note, that you don't need to search DOM for `$("#multiple-select")`, use [chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp) instead:

```
$("<select multiple id='multiple-select'>"+
      "<option value='1'>Apples</option>"+
      "<option value='2'>Oranges</option>"+
  "</select>"
)
.addClass('wide')
.appendTo("#wrapper")
.multipleSelect();
```

CSS:

```
.wide {
    min-width:200px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7v1cjpok/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and as @Kevin mentions, I was able to solve it with promise. I leave the code as a resource:

```
function createSelect(my_select) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        $("#div_select").html(my_select);
        resolve();
    });
}

async function dynamicSelect() {
    var array = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Casa'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Perro'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Gato'},
    ]
    var my_select = `<select id="my_select" name="cosas[]" multiple="multiple" class="selectmultiple">`;
    array.forEach(value => {
        my_select += `<option value="${value['id']}"> ${value['name']}</option>`;
    });

    my_select += `</select>`;
    await createSelect(my_select);
    $("#my_select").multipleSelect({
        width: "auto",
    });
}
dynamicSelect();
```